# Tesseract OCR with Gasmeter

Tags: android, image-processing, tesseract

I am trying to get Tesseract to recognize numbers from a photo of a gasmeter unit.
But it returns mostly empty pages as output.(I am using Tesseract 3.02)
For example

[pic 1, some tweaking](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/442/testnegate.png/)

I want to use Tesseract for an OCR App for Android, so I am just checking if Tesseract is even capable of recognize numbers like this. The first photo is as far as I could get with image preprocessing in my java programm.

If I use gimp and do some more tweaking manually, tesseract will recognize it. But I need it to recognize pictures like 1. Is there anything I can do to accomplish this?
->[pic 2, gimp tweak](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/outyb.png/)

Answer (score 3):

The first picture is actually giving correct output with the latest Tesseract version.

Tesseract sometimes gives empty page due to the segmentation logic it follows. In your case, it will try to segment the single word and as the result all those characters **will be treated as noise** and the recognition will fail.

If you are planning to recognize a photo of gasmeter unit, consider setting the **Page Segmentation Mode** of Tesseract to 8 (Which tells tesseract to assume the given image as a single word)

You might also consider other Page Segmentation Modes of tesseract

0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.

1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.

2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR

3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)

4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.

5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.

6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.

7 = Treat the image as a single text line.

8 = Treat the image as a single word.

9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.

10 = Treat the image as a single character.

To set a particular psm, use "tesseract -psm

I would suggest you one more thing. Since you want to recognize gasmeter value which has only digits, you can specify a custom **charset** in tesseract config file **containing only the digits**. The lower the size of the charset, the higher the accuracy of recogniztion. The charset should always contain the possible characters that the input image will have.

Even after trying all the above combinations, if tesseract is unable to recogize the input image properly, then try improving the quality of the input image by removing those unwanted  splotches. You can try using **ImageMagick** to clean the input image. Hope this helps.